# Programmatic creation of text input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, onchange, creation

I am currently learning JavaScript, and I got stuck at the following problems: I have tried to dynamically create an input of type text from JavaScript and to set its onChange method, but it is fired only when the page is loaded. In addition, `document.onload` does not work for creating my input, but window.onload does, although the tutorials I read claim that these two are almost the same thing. The code is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function f(value) {
                alert(value);
                return true;
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                if (document.getElementById("cloned") == null) {
                     var clonedInput = document.createElement('input');
                     clonedInput.type = 'text';
                     clonedInput.value = "";
                     clonedInput.id = 'cloned';
                     clonedInput.size = 20;
                     clonedInput.onChange = f(clonedInput.value);
                     var lastChild = document.getElementById("parent");
                     document.body.insertBefore(clonedInput, lastChild);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="toClone" type="text"/>
        <div id="parent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about creating an input field and setting it to hidden? Then when your event happens, display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f(clonedInput.value)` calls the function immediately and sets its *return value* (which is `true` in this case) as event handler.

You want to use an anonymous function:

```
clonedInput.onchange = function(){ f(this.value); };
```

**Note:** While HTML attributes are case-insensitive, JavaScript object properties are not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but when I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: That is not a really helpful error description... *edit:* `onChange` should be `onchange`: http://jsfiddle.net/tmQL5/

Comment: Now it works, thank you. Sorry for earlier, but it just didn't show the alert at all. I didn't know why, but now I think it was because of onChange written with C instead of c...

Comment: Correct... sorry, I didn't notice that at first.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this stuff works for window.onload, but not for document.onload?

Comment: Don't know, maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Answer (score 2):

You can actually clone the existing input element:

```
if (document.getElementById("cloned") == null) {
     var clonedInput = document.getElementById("toClone").cloneNode(true);
     clonedInput.id = 'cloned';
     clonedInput.onchange = f;
     var lastChild = document.getElementById("parent");
     document.body.insertBefore(clonedInput, lastChild);
}
```

Now to read the value change `f` to this:

```
function f() {
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);
    return true;
}
```

Edit: to make the cloned input reflect the first "live" you'll have to attach couple of events:

```
if (document.getElementById("cloned") == null) {
     var orgInput = document.getElementById("toClone");
     var clonedInput = orgInput.cloneNode(true);
     clonedInput.id = 'cloned';
     clonedInput.onchange = f;
     orgInput.onkeypress = ReflectValue;
     orgInput.onchange = ReflectValue;
     var lastChild = document.getElementById("parent");
     document.body.insertBefore(clonedInput, lastChild);
}
```

Then have this function:

```
function ReflectValue() {
    var cloned = document.getElementById("cloned");
    cloned.value = this.value;
}
```

Now whenever user type in the first input, it will reflect in the second input, and whenever user focus out it will also reflect any "non-keyboard" changes like pasting text.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. Do you have any idea why this stuff works for window.onload, but not for document.onload?

Comment: The `document` refers to the top element, parent of all other elements while `window` is more "general", not related directly to the elements - attaching the global events to `window` is the correct way - not sure why, sorry. If it's working, feel free to mark this answer as Accepted by ticking the empty V to the left. :)

Comment: Thank you, it works, but only if I refresh the page, otherwise, when I change the first field, the second is not updated.